# problema con cambio de estilo usando php y cambio de valores en echo

Tags: php, if

Estoy tratando de crear un estilo para mostrarlo si el campo es 1 ó 0

cuando es 1 y 0 me lo muestra bien , la cosa es que si me equivoco y deseo que 
    aparezca el estilo rojo el verde aun aparece.

```
<?php if($resultado['id_usuario_autoriza']): ?>
            <tr>

              <?php if($resultado['autorizado']): ?>
                <th style="color:green;">Autorizado Por:</th>
                <td style="color:green;"><?=$resultado_usuario_autoriza['personaNombre']?> <?=$resultado_usuario_autoriza['apellido']?><?php if ($resultado_usuario_autoriza['id_departamento']= 1) $departamento1 = "Sistemas"; ?>  <?php  echo $departamento1; ?></td>
              <?php elseif(!$resultado['autorizado']): ?>
                <th style="color:red;">No Autorizado Por:</th>
                <td style="color:red;"><?=$resultado_usuario_autoriza['personaNombre']?> <?=$resultado_usuario_autoriza['apellido']?></td>
              <?php endif; ?>

            </tr>
          <?php else: ?>
            <tr>

              <th>Autorizado Por:</th>
              <td>Sin Autorizar</td>

            </tr>
      <?php endif; ?>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aqui en la ultima imagen muestro lo que seteo al momento de autorizar  o deshautorizar la solicitud.

Comment: EL valor de $resultado['autorizado'] es un entero o un string?

Comment: es un entero @DavidLeonardoMolinaRuizDav

Comment: No entiendo que es lo que necesitas. Las imágenes me dan a entender que esta funcionando lo que quieres hacer. Mas allá de eso veo errores de sintaxis.

Comment: el problema que cuando cambio de valor , luego de autorizar a No autorizar el valor no se cambia... sigue siendo autorizado. como lo muestra en la primera imagen @FranIslas

Comment: Tu pregunta es confusa y tus comentarios también: *el problema que cuando cambio de valor  luego de autorizar a No autorizar el valor no se cambia...*  ¿dónde, cuándo, como? ¿Lanzas algún evento cuando cambias de valor para modificar los estilos? ¿Cuál es el código que cambia de un estilo a otro según esté autorizado o no de forma dinámica? No explicas nada sobre el contexto... Aparte de eso, el código se puede simplificar bastante, pero es necesario entender el contexto.

Comment: @A.Cedano tengo un campo en una base de datos llamado "autorizado" que recibe un 1 si se acepta una solicitud mediante un boton el cual asigna 1 al  campo y  0 si se presiona otro boton


los botones funcionan bien, pero si desahutorizo luego de autorizar me sigue apareciendo "autorizado" en verde y creo que es por como hice los if, esto te aclara? no se como explicartelo mas sencillo

Comment: Si tú cambias el estado de autorizado a desautorizado o viceversa, tienes que tener un *listener*  en el elemento que usas para hacer el cambio y en base a eso actualizar el color de forma dinámica. ¿El estado se cambia usando los dos botones que aparecen arriba a la derecha?

Comment: correcto, esos son los que uso para eso @A.Cedano , lo del  listener no lo se, solo uso php para mostrar mediante echo una  
color dependiendo el  resultado de una busqueda, trabajare mejor el if y regreso

Answer (score 0):

El campo `autorizado` tiene que ser `NULL` y despues hacer la modificación: `1` para `autorizado` y `2` para `pendiente`

```
if($resultado['autorizado'] == 1){
   echo "Autorizado";
} elseif($resultado['autorizado'] == 2) {
   echo "Pendiente";
}else {
   echo "No autorizado";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Juan mira este ejemplo muy sencillo. Pienso que es lo que necesitas. Si es así me dices y te indico también una forma más elegante de construir tus elementos en el código PHP.

Se recomienda usar clases CSS en vez de poner reglas de estilo directamente en los elementos. ¿Por qué? Por muchos motivos. Pongamos sólo uno: imagina una página con miles de archivos donde los estilos (colores, tamaños, márgenes...) están directamente en los elementos y hay necesidad de cambiar algo. Habrá que abrir los archivos y modificar de nuevo esos atributos in situ. Con reglas CSS cambias el valor solamente en el archivo CSS y el estilo se aplica a todos los elementos que tengan esa clase.

Aquí se aplica esa norma y verás lo fácil que resulta cambiar el color de verde a rojo o viceversa.

Espero te sirva.

```js
/*Asignamos un listener a todos los elementos con la clase "button"*/
document.querySelectorAll(".button").forEach(function(elem) {
  elem.addEventListener('click', setColor, false);
});

function setColor() {
  /*Referencia (por su id) a la fila que cambiará de color*/
  var trAutorizado = document.querySelector("#trf");
  /*Usamos el valor de name de cada botón para setear la clase CSS*/
  trAutorizado.className = this.name;
}
```

```css
.btn-autorizar {
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
}

.red {
  color: red;
}

.green {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.2/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="btn-autorizar">
  <a class="button is-success" name="green">Autorizar</a>
  <a class="button is-danger" name="red">No Autorizar</a>
</div>
<table class="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Nombre: </td>
      <td>Juan Ortiz</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tipo de solicitud:</td>
      <td>Soporte</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="green" id="trf">
      <td>Autorizado por: </td>
      <td>Juan Ortiz</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
```